# when connection times out using curl or get_file_contents to an API it kills my script

Tags: php, api

When the connection timesout when using curl or get_file_contents because of a network error or remote server doesn't respond for some reason it kills my script.

I am making these remote calls in a loop and if one fails it kills my script.

What is the best way to handle if a specific post fails, that it goes on to the next in the loop instead of the script dying?

Comment: post your code so far

Comment: What exactly happens at a timeout? Do you get an error (which could be caught)?

Comment: kingkero, I am posting records to multiple different server (10-15) constantly throughout the day. And what happens it seems is I post to the server and never get a response. I'm not sure if it's something like the tcp handshake isn't completing or the http response doesn't come. But my call just seems to sit there waiting and then eventually times out. It doesn't happen all to often but it wreaks havoc when it does because a batch of records that should have  been subsequently posted in the loop doesn't happen. I see byf-ferdy's solution and I think that will work for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First set a parameter for **CURL** for a timeout limit:

```
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1800);
```

The result of your `curl_exec()` call will show you if the request was successful or not:

```
for(/* anything */) {
    $ch = curl_init(); 
    //...
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if (!$result) {
        continue; // use this to jump to the next loop
    }

    // this code will not be executed if the request failed

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a try and catch block:

```
foreach (remote call....) {
    try {
       your current code
    } catch (Exception $e) {
       what to do if it fails
    }
}
```

If your whole script needs more time to run, use:

```
set_time_limit ( 500 ) // or however many seconds you need
```